# Webview does not support flex box on Android Jellybean

Tags: android, html, css, webview

I have a webview that loads a webpage which includes a flex box.
The flex box Div displays correctly on Kitkat Emulator but its not working on older Android versions such as Jellybean.
Boxes must be shown horizontally but they actually shown vertically.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>test</title>
</head>
    <body>
        <div style="display:flex; 
                                align-items: flex-start; 
                                justify-content: flex-start; 
                                flex-direction: row; 
                                flex-wrap: nowrap; 
                                width: 50%; height: 20%; 
                                background-color: red;">
            <div style="background-color: orange;">BOX 1</div>
            <div style="background-color: yellow;">BOX 2</div>
            <div style="background-color: green;">BOX 3</div>
        </div>
    </body>


</html>
```

Comment: this may sound like a goofy question but is there any chance I could see the code you ended up using? I've tried variations of `-webkit=box-flex: 1` and `-webkit-box-flex-direction: row` etc etc with no success so far.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you need to prefix everything according to the old flex box spec, like `-webkit-box-flex-foo: bar;`.

For direction, you might need to use orient instead, like: `-webkit-box-orient: vertical/horizontal;`.

Comment: You think correctly :) Source: http://caniuse.com/#search=flex (Android Browser is also Webview)

Comment: +1 I, too, was wondering why my layout is not properly set in Jellybean, while rest of them, work well.. Your answer + @Spinal, collectively, should be able to solve the problem... Thanks for atleast giving a way to think in a correct direction...:)